# What if my mmap virtual memory exceeds my computer’s RAM?

Tags: mmap

**Background and Use Case**

I have around 30 GB of data that never changes, specifically, every dictionary of every language.

Client requests to see the definition of a word, I simply respond with it.

On every request I have to conduct an algorithmic search of my choice so I don’t have to loop through the over two hundred million words I have stored in my .txt file.

If I open the txt file and read it so I can search for the word, it would take forever due to the size of the file (even if that file is broken down into smaller files, it is not feasible nor it is what I want to do).

I came across the concept  of mmap, mentioned to me as a possible solution to my problem by a very kind gentleman on discord.

**Problem**

As I was learning about mmap I came across the fact that mmap does not store the data on the RAM but rather on a virtual RAM… well regardless of which it is, my server or docker instances may have no more than 64 GB of RAM and that chunk of data taking 30 of them is quite painful and makes me feel like there needs to be an alternative that is better. Even on a worst case scenario, if my server or docker container does not have enough RAM for the data stored on mmap, then it is not feasible, unless I am wrong as to how this works, which is why I am asking this question.

**Questions**

Is there better solution for my use case than mmap?

Will having to access such a large amount of data through mmap so I don’t have to open and read the file every time allocate RAM memory of the amount of the file that I am accessing?

Lastly, if I was wrong about a specific statement I made on what I have written so far, please do correct me as I am learning lots about mmap still.

**Requirements For My Specific Use Case**

I may get a request from one client that has tens of words that I have to look up, so I need to be able to retrieve lots of data from the txt file effectively.

The response to the client has to be as quick as possible, the quicker the better, I am talking ideally a less than three seconds, or if impossible, then as quick as it can be.

Comment: The more common solution is to store your dictionary in a relational database on disks searchable by language and word.  As far as mmap, try loading your text file on a test machine and see what happens when you try and run your application.

Comment: How realtime it should be? You rather have to use a database

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc The issue is that I am not sure there is a way to conduct binary search (or any other algorythm) in a database like mongo db or any other, all before getting the data and then getting the data after the search. Also, by "on disks" do you mean having the database in the same server as the Rest API connectted to my client that is retrieving the data from whatever ssource I use?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I upated the question with infiormation regarding your question. It should be as fast as possible, so whatever technology and/or method allows me to do it fastest is what I will choose.

Comment: I said "relational database".  Not some NoSQL database like MongoDB.  Relational databases were designed for fast lookup by a key field made up of one or more elements using a binary search.  By "on disks", I meant having the database on the same server as the Rest API connected to the client that is retrieving the data.

Comment: Or a prefix tree, or even just a sorted set of fixed-length records. Data structures (your own, or those of an existing database) will be the key to a proper solution here. `mmap`  probably won’t be.

Comment: Sorry, brain fart time there, yes I am anyway using and planning to use SQL databases, for a second relational database meant document DB in my head, same problem about implementing my binary search applies tho “I am not sure there is a way to conduct binary search (or any other algorythm) in a relational database, all before getting the data and then getting the data after the search”. Also, about the in the same server disk database, it would be just like before deployment? Having the DB listening on a port of my server and the RestAPI on another?

Comment: You haven't explained your development, test, and production environments well enough for me to offer an opinion on the actual architecture you would use.  Generally, your Rest API communicates with the database and your client communicates with the Rest API.  The client is completely and absolutely unaware that a database exists,

Comment: By the way, your 20GB text file will take up 40 - 60 GB in a relational database.   The trade-off is more disk space for increased response time.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc “increased response time” so a relational database could be faster than using mmap? Also, yes, my problem would be solved if I use a relational database, I just need to be able to make it quick with a search algorithm, and I know the order of my entries since they are organized alphabetically, so  if a relational db allows me to say, make the id of the entries alphabetical and it conducts a binary search on that, that is fine.

Comment: I have no idea about using mmap.  A relational database is much faster than opening and reading through a 20GB text file.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I updated my last answer, in case you got the outdated comment.

Comment: @XaviFont Just throwing in (you might have thought on this) but for this use case you could take a look at using key value databases since I think the word -> definition perfectly fits the description here. And that way possibly you could store all the keys (all the words) in memory while the keys have pointers to values on disk - making it quite fast too.